# EF Core set foreign key as primary key with custom column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want `UserId` to be both the primary key and foreign key to `User.Id` so that the database column name is `UserId`.

I've tried searching online for solutions and tried using the `OnModelCreating` function and using the `[ForeignKey]` attribute but nothing worked.

Comment: You want the `UserId` in `Role` to be the primary key for that table? Does that make sense?? Then any user can have **at most** ***ONE*** role ..... really ?

Comment: Typically, for something like that, you need **3** tables - `User` (PK: `UserId`, other columns), `Role` (PK: `RoleID`, other columns) and `User_Roles` (PK: `UserId, RoleId`, possibly other columns) to handle that one user might have many roles, and a role might be assigned to many users

Comment: I basically need to store all the user's roles and searching online i found that you can't store arrays of primitives and that for this I needed to use 2 tables, one for the users and one for the role. I don't need a role Id, just the role name and a column that is the Id of the user that the role is assigned to. Users should be able to have multiple roles and not just one. I hope this explains it better

Comment: Well, the way you have it set up, one user can have zero or one role only - never more than one. And relational databases typically don't handle "arrays" or multiple values in a single cell very well - it's also against the **first normal form** of relational database design to do so ....

Comment: Would there be a better way of storing an array of roles? I read that there is also a way to store them by JSON serializing the array data added to the column in the `OnModelCreating()` function

Comment: The setup with the three tables - user, role and a join table - is the proper relational way of doing this

Comment: I'm pretty new to relational databases, would you mind clarifying what the third table (join) would be used for and how it should be set up?

Comment: Read any good tutorial and look for "m-to-n" or "many-to-many" relationships - that's the "blueprint" for how to handling that use case in a relational database. Try [this](https://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html) or [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/database-design-basics-eb2159cf-1e30-401a-8084-bd4f9c9ca1f5) as starting points

Answer (score 1):

based on the comments, I answer this question with three table to implement many-to-many relationship between User and Role. one more table is needed which call it User_Role.

First modify the role class and remove UserId, and add RoleId:

```
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Second User_Role class has two fk(one for user class and one for role class) and two navigational properties:

```
public class User_Role
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Third, edit User class and instead of using ICollection <Role, use ICollection<User_Role>:

Fourth, in OnmodelCreating, your config would be something like this to achieve many-to-many relationships:
-define a composite PK:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User_Role>()
        .HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });
```

This ensures that the combination of UserId and RoleId must be unique in the User_Role table.

-one-to-many relationship between User and User_Role:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User_Role>()
    .HasOne(ur => ur.User)
    .WithMany(u => u.User_Roles)
    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
```

-one-to-many relationship, but between Role and User_Role:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User_Role>()
    .HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
    .WithMany(r => r.User_Roles)
    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: When I query the database to get the user, `user.Roles` is null